# Component returned failure code: 0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) [amIAddonManagerStartup.readStartupData] with GeckoDriver Mozilla Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am starting with Selenium WebDriver and Ecplise. 
After configuring the Eclipse and running simple code to launch the website I am getting an error.

Additionally added to the project:
selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
geckodriver.exe v.0.24.0
Win 10 x64bit
Java 1.8

Firefox version - 56.0

I have checked the answers on github and stackoverflow but most of them do not have full answers or are not fully related to the issue I am facing with.

```
1550323864077   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\Tatiana\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofile.owPgCVvcxBRf"
1550323864448   addons.xpi  WARN    Error parsing extensions state: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) [amIAddonManagerStartup.readStartupData]"  nsresult: "0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm :: loadExtensionState :: line 1554"  data: no] Stack trace: loadExtensionState()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:1554 < getInstallState()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:1589 < checkForChanges()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:3109 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:2188 < callProvider()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:269 < _startProvider()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:739 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:906 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:3090 < observe()@jar:file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mozilla%20Firefox/omni.ja!/components/addonManager.js:65
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\Tatiana\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
1550323864794   Marionette  INFO    Enabled via --marionette
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\Tatiana\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\Tatiana\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\Tatiana\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
Unable to read VR Path Registry from C:\Users\Tatiana\AppData\Local\openvr\openvrpaths.vrpath
[Child 21116] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 21116] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
1550323866147   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 55177
[Child 24700] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 24700] WARNING: pipe[Child 2052] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/build/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 346
[Child 2052] WARNING: pipe errconsole.error: 
  Message: Error: Transaction canceled due to a closed connection.
  Stack:
    executeTransaction/promise<@resource://gre/modules/Sqlite.jsm:559:15
observe@resource://gre/modules/AsyncShutdown.jsm:534:9

*** UTM:SVC TimerManager:registerTimer called after profile-before-change notification. Ignoring timer registration for id: telemetry_modules_ping
[GPU 9072] WARNING: pipe error: 109
###!!! [Child][MessageChannel::SendAndWait] Error: Channel error: cannot send/recv

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: 
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'MININT-K1IIBT8', ip: '192.168.2.101', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
remote stacktrace: WebDriverError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:227:5
InvalidSessionIDError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:382:5
assert.that/<@chrome://marionette/content/assert.js:383:13
assert.session@chrome://marionette/content/assert.js:49:3
execute/req<@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:536:9
TaskImpl_run@resource://gre/modules/Task.jsm:331:42
TaskImpl@resource://gre/modules/Task.jsm:280:3
asyncFunction@resource://gre/modules/Task.jsm:252:14
Task_spawn@resource://gre/modules/Task.jsm:166:12
execute@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:529:15
onPacket@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:500:7
_onJSONObjectReady/<@chrome://marionette/content/transport.js:501:9

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:147)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:125)
    at Banking.main(Banking.java:27)
```

The Firefox should be opened, and the link should be opened
The browser starts with the blank window

Comment: Updated Firefox to latest version 65.0.1 and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
1550323864448   addons.xpi  WARN    Error parsing extensions state: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) [amIAddonManagerStartup.readStartupData]"  nsresult: "0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm :: loadExtensionState :: line 1554"  data: no] Stack trace: loadExtensionState()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:1554 < getInstallState()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:1589 < checkForChanges()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:3109 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:2188 < callProvider()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:269 < _startProvider()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:739 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:906 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:3090 < observe()@jar:file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mozilla%20Firefox/omni.ja!/components/addonManager.js:65
.
.
[Child 2052] WARNING: pipe errconsole.error: 
  Message: Error: Transaction canceled due to a closed connection.
  Stack:
    executeTransaction/promise<@resource://gre/modules/Sqlite.jsm:559:15
observe@resource://gre/modules/AsyncShutdown.jsm:534:9

*** UTM:SVC TimerManager:registerTimer called after profile-before-change notification. Ignoring timer registration for id: telemetry_modules_ping
[GPU 9072] WARNING: pipe error: 109
###!!! [Child][MessageChannel::SendAndWait] Error: Channel error: cannot send/recv

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException:
```

...implies that the **GeckoDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Firefox Browser** session.

---

You haven't mentioned if you are using either of the following:

- *Jenkins*
- *TeamCity Slave*
- *GeckoDriver* / *Mozilla* as *Windows Service*

However, as per the *GitHub* discussion with a similar issue and *trace logs* tittled [Firefox 54.1.0 not able to launch with gecko driver (v0.18.0) in TeamCity slave machine (run as windows service)](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/847) @andreastt clearly mentions:

> we don’t support running Firefox or geckodriver as a Windows service.

where OP was running **TeamCity** agent instance as **Window Service**.

You can also find a relevant discussion in [Not able to run Firefox with geckodriver and jenkins slave machine as windows service](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/466)

---

### Mandatory aspects

Ensure that the binaries you are using are version compatible with respect to *GeckoDriver*, *Selenium* and *Firefox* as per the following compatibility chart:

[image: supported_platforms_geckodriver_24]

---

### trivia

- [Maximize Window errors with "Failed to find width field"](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/820)
- [unable to open Firefox URL](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1246)
- [Context click options doesn't work with Mozilla Firefox](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/738)

Answer (score 0):

Get your firefox version:

```
firefox -v
Mozilla Firefox 106.0.5
```

Get your geckodriver version:

```
geckodriver -V
geckodriver 0.32.0 (4563dd583110 2022-10-13 09:22 +0000)
```

Get your selenium version (example uses python):

```
pip show selenium
Version: 4.6.0
```

Now check the [geckodriver supported platforms page](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Support.html).

**Ubuntu only:**

Unfortunately, ubuntu only has the latest firefox version available to the package managers - whether `snap` or `apt`.

You must download the precompiled binaries from their [releases page](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/)

In this case v77.0.1, was chosen:

```
# Install packages for expected shared libraries
sudo apt install libgtk-3-0 libdbus-glib-1-2

# libdbus-glib-1-2 - deprecated library for D-Bus IPC
# libgtk-3-0 - GTK graphical user interface library

cd /opt
sudo wget https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/77.0.1/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-77.0.1.tar.bz2
sudo tar -xf firefox-77.0.1.tar.bz2
sudo mv firefox/ /usr/lib/firefox
# symlink to the binary
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
```

Check version:

```
firefox --version
Mozilla Firefox 77.0.1
```

Now install the compatible `geckodriver` and `selenium` versions.

### Sources

- [Gist: Installing a particular firefox version on linux](https://gist.github.com/stephenharris/90bb468bf80e7f7b02e8b8afe694de4f)